# Finding the best option on how to fill storage decks

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, mathematical-optimization

I will make an abstraction of the issue I am trying to devise a strategy for.

The problem at hand is the following:

I've got two storage decks. One of them is a 5 story storage deck in which I can put 5 rectangular boxes at a time. The second deck is a 4 story storage deck with 3 compartments, into which I can put 12 square boxes at a time.

Let me draw this:

```
rectangular
box 
deck
---------          square box
|       |          deck
---------          -------------
|       |          |   |   |   |
---------          -------------
|       |          |   |   |   |
---------          -------------
|       |          |   |   |   |
---------          -------------
|       |          |   |   |   |
---------          -------------
```

For the sake of easier understanding of the problem, let's say the boxes are for different customers, and they never order less than three boxes at a time, and they want them in the order they went into the storage deck. It is also not acceptable to keep a customer waiting because a box of a different customer is in the way and we cannot get it out of the storage decks. We only process one customer at a time when taking boxes out of the storage deck.

The boxes are of 5 different colors, and the way they are manufactured, it is best to produce equal colors together, because it takes about 5 minutes to change the color and we've got no time to waste. Now, we join a finite number of orders together, but not as much as not to fill more than 70% of our storage decks with all our boxes for this finite number of orders, because it takes a while to get one customer's order out of the storage decks.

Boxes are also of 3 different qualities and they can have openings on the top or on the bottom.

Orders of customers for boxes of odd/even parity will be exchangingly rectangular or square. If the boxes of odd parity are square, then boxes of even parity will be rectangular. If the boxes of odd parity are rectangular, then boxes of odd parity will be square.

After we manufacture the sides of the boxes, they have to sit for a while to let the paint dry. The sides dry in a separate storage deck, where we cannot mix sides for rectangular/square boxes / different colors / different qualities / different positions of the opening together. There is a finite number of places for sides in every story.

An abstraction of it, with characters representing different types & colors:

```
-----------------------
| . . . . .           |
-----------------------
| * * * * * * *       |
-----------------------
| ^ ^ ^ ^ ^           |
-----------------------
| . . .               |
-----------------------
|                     |
-----------------------
```

As there are finite places for the number of boxes and a finite number of decks on which the sides can dry, it's best to join orders and boxes in such a way, that we get the maximum out of this storage deck.

Some situations are completely unacceptable, such as "getting double parked" with boxes of other customers, some situations are merely inconvenient as far as time to manufacture the orders goes.

I think you get the idea, that the number of variables and possible combinations in play is many.

Now time for the real question, as **I am not asking for an algorithm**, merely advice on how to approach the problem. It seems to me that there are so many variables at play, that to try and devise a deterministic algorithm for it would be tedious and extremely error prone and time consuming. I was thinking something along the lines of trial-and-error simulation of all the possibilities, where I would simply not consider the ones that are unacceptable and compare the inconveniences of the other possibilies. Ofcourse every inconvenience has some sort of 'weight'.

I'm going to do this in Java, and I wouldn't want it to calculate forever, as I need this to recalculate on the fly whenever orders are added / removed or the percentage of occupancy of storage deck changes.

Any helpful tips on this? Which algorithms, libraries I could use?

EDIT: not sure why the popular opinion seems to be that this question should be closed, when I am just asking for some pointers in the right direction? I've got no experience in AI or machine learning or anything of the sorts and I would just like to get some advice on how to approach the problem and where to start...

Comment: This is way too broad. Without a mathematical-definition it's hard to develop anything (it should be your first step). But it surely is a typical combinatorial-optimization problem and all usual approaches come to mind (sometimes combined): SAT-solvers, Constraint-programming, Mixed-integer programming and Local-search/Meta-heuristics. (CP being probably the easiest to implement e.g. using Choco)

Comment: your problem is from operations research, you need to define a goal-function, that will define your "profit" and then you need to define all kinds of constraints, that will bound your possible result-space. You can then use a solver and get a solution using `Branch and bound` algorithm, since you will definitely have some discrete variables here. Not sure if I used right terms, not a native speaker here:)

Comment: wait a second, when you add a new order, do you need to recalculate based on the last state or do you have to respect the last state?

Comment: the ones i'm already producing can stay (let's say my algorithm chooses to join three at a particular point and I start producing those), the rest need to be recalculated @JohnnyAW

Comment: hmm, maybe in this case your best choice would be some kind of greedy algorithm, like take the next best possible space, since you don't really know what will come next. Or you could define further constraints based on the current state, that will help to keep your result-space small(faster calculation time)

Comment: The popular opinion to close probably comes from the fact that it's a hard problem without a formal-enough presentation. Be careful. A lot of suggestions might be motivated by some incomplete understanding of your task and will only waste time until you recognize this when approaching it with some idea. It's still unclear if feasibility or optimization is your main problem here. If it's the first, Greedy won't help and even the feasibilty-problem is probably NP-hard. Adding to that, this might also touch online-algorithms or even stochastic-optimization(unknown future) which makes it worse

Comment: Both feasibility and optimization are the goal @sascha

Comment: I can try making a mathematical description of the problem but I am not really sure how..